# Explicit infinite search boundary in URLs

Tags: feature-request, search, hyperlinks

#### Problem

The Stack Exchange search engine allows some parameters with boundaries, like

```
votes..0
votes:0..3
votes3..
```

There's a problem with the boundary from X to infinity:

```
https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=votes%3A0..
```

When used in a question, answer, or a comment the trailing dots are not parsed as a link (also check with the comment behind this post):

https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=votes%3A0..

#### Proposed solution

Search page URL should have a trailing `+` symbol, [which becomes a space in the search string](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/261000/296059). The search query should stay the same, and the URL be like

```
https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=votes%3A0..+
```

https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=votes%3A0..+

Such link should open like this (no change from current behaviour):

> [image]

I'm aware of the `+` symbol and can add it manually. But it would be great **if the URL automatically contained it**, so anybody who copy-pastes the URL string would have a valid URL.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=votes%3A0..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add a + to the end of the URL:

- https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=votes%3A0..+

Alternatively, you can forcibly treat the entire string as a link, using standard Markdown:

- https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=votes%3A0..

  ```
  <https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=votes%3A0..>
  ```

Comment: Thanks, it solves half the issue. Indeed, I'd like this to be added to URL by the engine, so that everybody gets a valid URL by copying it from a browser tab.

Comment: @Nick This is more of a problem with the Markdown parsing process. Both URLs, with and without +, are valid and work correctly. It's just that the auto-linking on plain links doesn't hyperlink the entire link. You can force this in numerous ways with Markdown, but the original link *is* a valid URL.

Comment: I agree that it is valid. But since there's seems to be no way to fix it directly in Markdown (what if I just put a dot after my link?), I'd like to have this crutch. So it's a crutch-request, heh )